# libvirtd with qemu: ryzen cpu emulation on intel host?

Tags: virtualization, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I try to set the settings of my virtual machine as my ryzen laptop. The VM is on an host with intel CPU. But I already stuck on setting the correct model. I can't find Ryzen.

libvirtd version: 6.1.0
qemu version: 4.2.0

How can I specify Ryzen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ryzen is in the same family as EPYC, so you want CPU model name "EPYC" / "EPYC-IBPB" - see also https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/target-i386.html#recommendations-for-kvm-cpu-model-configuration-on-x86-hosts

That said, if the VM is running on a host with Intel CPUs, you are not going to be able to pick a EPYC CPU model for it, because that is not capable of running on an Intel host due to mis-matched features.

Comment: Oh, good to know. I just tried it. As you said, it is not working. Do you think/know of an other hypervisor which supports such things (Virtualbox, ...) ?

Comment: The problem is not related to the hypervisor. It is a matter of the CPU hardware - EPYC has features which Intel CPUs can't support and vica-verca.